# Omniauth && devise no route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I trying to use omniauth to do login with social networks. 
I using this [wiki](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/omniauth/master/frames) but i have no success

There is my code:

Routes.rb

```
 get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'auth#create'
```

my auth controller:

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController
  def create
    p request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end

  def vkontakte

  end

  def facebook
  end
end
```

Why i have route error?

```
No route matches [GET] "/auth/vkontakte"
```

Thnks

Comment: I believe you have to set your provider in your config. https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#getting-started

Comment: Sure, i've done all like in wiki

Comment: Can you paste the link you are using to access oath?

Comment: i use :
`link_to "auth with vk" , 'auth/vkontakte'`
So link will be /auth/vkontakte

Comment: don't you need to call with `'auth/vkontakte/callback'`?

Comment: it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you have to do some config in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

`config.omniauth :vkontakte, APP_ID, APP_SECRET`
The you need to add something like

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

with that you can implement the method in the

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def vkontakte
    # you can do anything you want to do here. Note that you have access to the `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` which holds all the user information you'd require.
  end
end
```

One more thing: if you check the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers), you'd find different configuration options, but always be careful not to overwrite/create AuthController because by default that's what Omniauth uses, I think and I believe in order to work with devise, you should be inheriting some stuff from `Devise` not `ApplicationController`.